# Route a Workflow to a Person Group in Maximo

Tags: workflow, roles, maximo

I am creating a workflow for a work order in Maximo. I am trying to route the workflow on the work order to a Person group and allow anyone on that Person Group to then route and approve the work order. I have a task node with a role attached that references the Person Group I need. When I create my work order only the group default has access to change the work order not the whole group. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this or some work around to allow any person who is apart of the group to route the work order when they opens and view it?

Comment: Is the role's Broadcast value set to True? Because if it is, each group member should get an assignment and then should be able to route the WF.

Answer (score 2):

in roles application you have to set broadcast to true, also make sure that all persons in the person group either don't have site/org defined or they all share similar site as the WO site.